# Defining an Array of type Class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, header

I'm trying to define an array of type Class, for my homework.  The classB and classC is defined inside another classA, and I have to define the an Array which
is defined inside classC of type classB. Below is the code I'm writing.

```
//main.cpp
...
//cop.h
class cop
{
    public:
        ....
        class Person
        {
            private:
                static char name;
                static char age;
                static char gender;
        };
        class Station
        {
            public:
                Station();
                ~Station();
            private:
                Person personArray[20];
            protected:
                void visit();

        };

//cop.cpp
char cop::Person::name;
char cop::Person::age;
char cop::Person::gender;

cop::Station::Station(){}
cop::Station::~Station(){}
Person cop::Station::personArray[20];
```

I get following ERROR;

> 'Person' does not name a type

Comment: Mixing namespace and classes, are you?

Comment: Do you _really_ want all the `Person` instances to share single instances of each `name`, `age` and `gender`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (as I'm pointing out later) the fields of `Person` should not be `static`. After that, remove the following lines:

```
char cop::Person::name;
char cop::Person::age;
char cop::Person::gender;

Person cop::Station::personArray[20];
```

Properly designed your code should read like the following:

```
    // Person.h
    class Person
    {
        public:
            char name;
            char age;
            char gender;
    };

    // Station.h
    class Station
    {
        public:
            Station();
            ~Station();
        private:
            Person personArray[20];
        protected:
            void visit();

    };

    // Station.cpp
    Station::Station()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            personArray[i].age = ...;
        }
    }
```

By the way: declaring all fields of the `Person` class `static` will definitely make sure that all persons in your array have the same name, age and gender...

Comment: The `name`, `age` and `gender` lines are necessary because these have been declared as `static` members of the class.  Whether or not that is correct is dubious, as I've pointed out in my comment to the OP.

Comment: OK, I understand that, as I've pointed out, having all persons have the same name, age and gender doesn't seem useful... I'll change my sample code accordingly.